# Formula for the number of binary combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

What is the formula for knowing the number of binary combinations, where n is the total number of digits and k is the maximum number of digits 1. Only those ending in 1 will be counted.

Example: n = 2, k = 3, it has 2 combinations 01 and 11;

Example: n = 3. k = 3, it has 4 combinations 111, 101, 111 and 001;

Example: n = 5, k = 3. it has 11 combinations;

For context: It is a challenge from the teacher to the class, he passed this question on to come up with a formula and ask us to make a code that generates the result. I’m days trying to get to the formula but I always make the mistake

Comment: What is the context for this, and do you have any thoughts/failed attempts? Also, did you mean for your example to have $k=3$? If $k>n$ then $k$ is irrelevant since you can't have more $1$s than you have digits.

Comment: K is the maximum number of 1, if less, k will be limited to N. n = 2 and k = 3, it was just an example. I need to arrive in a closed formula using N and K, but I'm not getting

Comment: The context would really help. Is this for a competition? A combinatorics class? Did this come up in a programming project you're working on? An interview question? What do you know about similar problems/combinatorics already? What are your thoughts on this problem/attempts to tackle it? All of this would help us help you in an appropriate way.

Comment: It is a challenge from the teacher to the class, he passed this question on to come up with a formula and ask us to make a code that generates the result. I’m days trying to get to the formula but I always make the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that if the last digit "1" is in last position, we have to select at most $k-1$ "unit" digits before that (the rest of the digits being zeros). Therefore if we intend to select $p$ digits "one" ($o \le p \le k-1$), meaning selecting $p$ "places" among $n-1$ places:

$$\begin{cases}\text{if} & p=0:& \ \binom{0}{n-1} \ \text{possibilities}\\
\text{if}  & p=1:& \ \binom{1}{n-1}{1} \ \text{possibilities}\\
... & ... & ...\\
\text{if}  & p=k-2:& \ \binom{n-1}{k-2} \ \text{possibilities}\\
\text{if}  & p=k-1:& \ \binom{n-1}{k-1} \ \text{possibilities}
\end{cases}$$

Threfore the result is:

$$\sum_{p=0}^{p=k-1}\binom{n-1}{p}$$

BUT there is no closed form formula for this sum as you can see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17202)